# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable in a django code

Tags: python, django

```
@property
def pmt_loaner_final(self):
    return float(self.pmt_loaner_new) + float(self.debit_fee)

@property
def pmt_broker_final(self):
    return float(self.pmt_broker_new) + float(self.debit_fee)

@property
def total_compounded_broker(self):
    return self.compounded_amount(self.brokerage_fees)

@property
def total_compounded_loaner(self):
    return self.compounded_amount(self.amount)



def compounded_amount(self, amount):
        """
        Return the amount of interest pad for a given days amount
        """
        interests_amount = math.pow(
            (1 + self.daily_interest), self.padding_days)
        total_post_daily_extra_interest = float(
            amount) * float(interests_amount)
        return total_post_daily_extra_interest

@property
def final_credit_rate(self):
    return self.get_final_credit_rate(
        self.final_pmt_without_withdrawal_fees,
        self.total_compounded)



def get_final_credit_rate(self, pmt, interest):
        pmt *= -1
        final_rate = numpy.rate(self.debits_count, pmt, interest, 0, 1)
        final_nominal_rate = final_rate * self.compounding_periods
        return abs(math.pow((1 + (
            final_nominal_rate / self.compounding_periods)),
            self.compounding_periods) - 1)
```

I have a function `discount` which give me the error :

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

@property
def discount(self):
    return self.final_credit_rate(
        self.pmt_loaner_final + self.pmt_broker_final,
        self.total_compounded_loaner + self.total_compounded_broker
    )
```

Could any be able to help me at this point?

```
In [7]: a = computation.pmt_loaner_final

In [8]: computation.pmt_broker_final
Out[8]: 15.075747029391236

In [9]: b = computation.pmt_broker_final

In [10]: computation.total_compounded_loaner
Out[10]: 501.6459987947617

In [11]: c = computation.total_compounded_loaner

In [12]: computation.total_compounded_broker
Out[12]: 170.55963959021898

In [13]: d = computation.total_compounded_broker

In [14]: computation.final_credit_rate(a+b, c+d)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/jeremie/Projects/credit-24-django/loanwolf/products/tests.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 computation.final_credit_rate(a+b, c+d)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Another point I have :

```
In [8]: a = computation.final_pmt_without_withdrawal_fees

In [9]: b = computation.total_compounded

In [10]: computation.get_final_credit_rate(a,b)
Out[10]: 0.3296931087692383
```

So the problem is really on final credit rate. Knowing that the additions `a+b` and `c+d` aren't a problem.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: My guess is that this thing is a float: `self.compounded_amount`.

Comment: BTW, how do you adding two function `self.pmt_loaner_final + self.pmt_broker_final`?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque We could do that because pmt_loaner_final and pmt_broker_final will return float

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I did that for many functions and all worked except `discount`

Comment: But, shouldn't it be `self.pmt_loaner_final() + self.pmt_broker_final()`? You aren't calling the functions.

Comment: No, I'm calling properties. Don't stuck on that. I am pretty sure the addition works fine.

Comment: this question is useless without a fullstacktrace (which I see that someone has already suggested that you post)

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question

Comment: Could you tell me if it is ok @e4c5? Is there something missing?

Comment: Yes you are missing a full stacktrace

Comment: min, I'll show you something. I didn't know what was a stacktrace, sorry

Comment: @e4c5 Is this what you want?

Comment: It looks to me like you're calling `final_credit_rate(a, b)`. However, this is a property that takes no arguments. So, in Python, I think since it's a property, `X.final_credit_rate` is a float, so calling (a, b) on it doesn't work. Did you mean `get_final_credit_rate()`

Answer (score 3):

The "**is not callable**" in **TypeError: 'float' object is not callable**, probably means that you are trying to call property, which cannot be called, instead accessed. OR, you're calling a method, when a property with the same name is available in your scope. I think in your case it's the former.

In simple words - you have `final_credit_rate` decorated as a property (`@property` before above the `def`). This means you cannot call it using the parenthesis at the end, but as a simple property access:

```
computation.final_credit_rate
```

---

**Probable solutuion**:

To use it as a method, remove the `@property` decorator, and specify the 2 parameters in the definition, and then make the call

```
computation.final_credit_rate(a+b, c+d)
```